# Color picker value not binding with aurelia

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker, aurelia

I am trying to use spectrum color picker in Aurelia. I've initialized the spectrum color picker in my project file like this

editBoard.js

```
import "spectrum-colorpicker";
@autoinject()
export class Read {
    board = {
          color:"#FFFFFF"
       };

    attached() {
        $("#colorpicker").spectrum();
    }
}
```

editBoard.html

```
<template>
    <require from="spectrum-colorpicker/spectrum.css"></require>
    <input type='text' id="colorpicker" value.two-way="board.color" />
    <div css="color : ${board.color};" style="width:100%; 
    height:100px;"></div>
</template>
```

when I load it, it is coming alright. The color picker is working well and it had picked up the color that I gave the input via the `value.two-way="board.color"` but the problem is that when I change the color from the color picker, only the input value is changed, the `board.color` value is not changed. Any reason why this is happening, are there any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a gist for a custom element wrapper for spectrum: https://gist.github.com/arabsight/cf9c588b60824eddd30f97accc634c17

you can use it like this:

```
<spectrum color.bind="board.color"></spectrum>
```

what you're missing in your code is listening to the change event of the picker and updating the value.